# has_many through relationship to the same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have User table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :broker_clients, :class_name => "BrokerClients", :foreign_key => "broker_id"
  has_many :clients, :through => :broker_clients, :foreign_key => "broker_id"
  has_many :brokers, :through => :broker_clients, :foreign_key => "client_id"
end
```

And BrokerClients table:

```
class BrokerClients < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broker, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User"
end
```

Now when I create a relationship:

```
>> BrokerClients.create(broker_id: User.first.id, client_id: User.last.id)
  User Load (9.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   (1.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (41.5ms)  INSERT INTO "broker_clients" ("broker_id", "client_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["broker_id", 4], ["client_id", 210], ["created_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 13:43:27 EDT -04:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 13:43:27 EDT -04:00]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<BrokerClients id: 1, broker_id: 4, client_id: 210, created_at: "2014-10-10 17:43:27", updated_at: "2014-10-10 17:43:27">
>> User.first.brokers.first
```

When I try to get clients it's working fine:

```
>> User.first.clients.first
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "broker_clients" ON "users"."id" = "broker_clients"."
=> #<User id: 210, ....
```

But for the client when I try to get the brokers related to it wont work:

```
>> User.last.brokers.first
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "broker_clients" ON "users"."id" = "broker_clients"."broker_id" WHERE "broker_clients"."broker_id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["broker_id", 210]]
=> nil
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in the `User modal` as:--

```
has_many :broker_clients, :class_name => "BrokerClients", :foreign_key => "broker_id"
has_many :clients, :through => :broker_clients, :foreign_key => "broker_id"

has_many :inverse_broker_clients, :class_name => "BrokerClients", :foreign_key => "client_id"
has_many :brokers, :through => :inverse_broker_clients, :foreign_key => "client_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your insert vs. your query:

Insert:

> SQL (41.5ms)  INSERT INTO "broker_clients" ("broker_id", "client_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["broker_id", 4], ["client_id", 210], ["created_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 13:43:27 EDT -04:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 13:43:27 EDT -04:00]]

Queries:

> User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "broker_clients" ON "users"."id" = "broker_clients"."broker_id" WHERE "broker_clients"."broker_id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["broker_id", 210]]

You insert (broker_id=4, client_id=210) but you query for broker_id=210.  That's why you're getting nil for `brokers.first`.  Pretty sure you're foreign keys are backwards:

```
has_many :clients, :through => :broker_clients, :foreign_key => "broker_id"
has_many :brokers, :through => :broker_clients, :foreign_key => "client_id"
```

Should be

```
has_many :clients, :through => :broker_clients, :foreign_key => "client_id"
has_many :brokers, :through => :broker_clients, :foreign_key => "broker_id"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I changed foreign_key as you suggested. But still having the same issue. I have one relationship (=> #<BrokerClients id: 1, broker_id: 4, client_id: 210, created_at: "2014-10-10 17:43:27", updated_at: "2014-10-10 17:43:27">). When I try to User.first.clients.first.id => 210, but when I do User.last.brokers.first I'm getting nil :(

Comment: First, restart your server if you didn't already.  Second, please post your SQL queries after you've updated the foreign_key relationships as recommended.  As far as I can tell correcting the foreign_key references should resolve your issue.  Essentially you're pointing the has_many relationship at the wrong objects (ie. broker -> client, client -> broker).

Comment: Additionally one of your SQL queries in the original post is cut off.  It would be helpful to know what the full query is.

Comment: Actually I changed it and restated the console. As for the full log https://gist.github.com/eqbal/38006bb9e55295187fa1.